# looking for text control that is easy to data bind and text highlight wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am looking for some control that can do following 2 :

1.highlight some of the text in different colors.

1. easy databind.

checked richtextbox - but it is hard to databind with it.

checked textbox but it problem to text hight light with it.

any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RichTextBox - or even better the Extended RichTextBox here (it allows easy DataBinding): http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox.

If you don't want to have to include another control you can create an AttachedProperty to make it possible to bind to the built in RichTextBox. Check this out here: http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor